# Why is this ionic template showing blank page?

Tags: angularjs, templates, ionic-framework

I have a simple ionic project. My `index.html` shows any change I make. However, I am trying to include a template file. That isn't showing in the webpage. Here's my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="eliteApp">
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module("eliteApp", ["ionic"])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider) {

    $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "app/home/home.html"
    });

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title">Elite Schedule</h1>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-tabs class="tabs-energized tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab title="Leagues" icon="ion-home" href="#">
        <ion-view></ion-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="My Teams" icon="ion-star" href="#">
        <ion-view></ion-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I am following a tutorial. However, I don't see any specific code that imports the template onto my `index.html` file. Am I missing something?

Comment: where is your home.html file. In which folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so there was an error. Instead or `$urlRouterProvider`, I wrote `$urlRouteProvider`, without the `r` in both the places. Now the page shows, but I can't see the header text! :-/

Answer (score 1):

Your default state was `/` but you doesn't have configured a state with url `/`.

So.. with `/home` should work:

```
$urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

Comment: Nope. The `/home` url doesn't work. It shows `Cannot GET /home` on the screen. Inside the `www` folder I have `index.html` and `app` folder. Inside `app` folder I have `home` folder and inside that I have `home.html`.

Answer (score 0):

In your html in your `index.html` you have:

```
  <body ng-app="eliteApp">
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

The `<ion-nav-view>` is what links your other views to this one. So as long as your `templateUrl` is correct, it should work if you enter the address `.../home'`. To make it default to your `home.html`, change your `$urlRouteProvider` to `$urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/home')`.